# how to refresh screen in ai2?

Tags: app-inventor

I am making a simple social network app using App Inventor 2.
When a user follows another user, I need the follow button to become unfollow button and this works.
But when I click on unfollow buttton it shows follow notifier message, so is there a way I can make a hidden refresh so all the data recieved from database is updated?

Comment: what about using a simple logic like this:`if button text = "follow" then show follow notifier message else show unfollow notifier message`?

Comment: I am already doing it, but it doesn`t take action from first follow, I have to press follow twice so it changes, thats why I am looking for a refresh.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks.